# Copy row from one table to another, with a new primary key

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to copy a row from table A into table B - but want table B to generate a new primary key. Whatever I do, it just copies over the Primary Key from table A.

My primary key is col1. My current SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO tableB (col2, col3, col4) 
  (SELECT NULL, tableA.col2, tableA.col3, tableA.col4   
   FROM  tableA  
   WHERE tableAD.col1 = xxx)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the schema for both tables ?

Comment: They're completely identical (except I gave one table a different primary key name, in the hope that it would help!):  ID int(11), firstname varchar(30), lastname varchar(30), time(timestamp).

Comment: Why are you selecting tableB.col2, shouldn't this be tableA.col2

Comment: `SELECT tableB.col2, tableB.col3, tableB.col4` without the `NULL` should work better

Comment: No, that doesn't work I'm afraid - that's what I tried first.

Comment: As a point of courtesy by the way, please don't down-vote questions... Obviously there's a problem in the question, otherwise it wouldn't be on here!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting 4 columns but in the `insert` statement there are 3 columns to insert. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO tableB (col2, col3, col4) 
  (SELECT tableB.col2, tableB.col3, tableB.col4   
   FROM  tableA  
   WHERE tableA.col1 = xxx)
```

Comment: I tried that as an earlier iteration, doesn't work either I'm afraid...

Comment: Nope - you're kinda right, but your code is wrong: I've adapted it below.

Answer (score 0):

You were selecting from TableB.  Try

```
INSERT INTO tableB (col2, col3, col4) 
     (SELECT tableA.col2, tableA.col3, tableA.col4   
      FROM  tableA  
      WHERE tableAD.col1 = xxx)
```

For TableB you should create a primary key column and this should probably be a auto-increment.

Comment: Sorry - this was my error changing the table names for stackoverflow! Obviously I'm not actually copying from tableB...

Comment: Oh - and as I said above, my tableB has a primary key too, and that auto-increments.

Answer (score 0):

Key was Elbek's comment about inserting four columns. My code should have been:

INSERT INTO tableB (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
   (SELECT NULL, tableA.col2, tableA.col3, tableA.col4
   FROM  tableA
   WHERE tableAD.col1 = xxx)